# View in the design editor of android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android-studio, view

I am trying to follow the tutorial of android studio in the android official website. during the time to review View in the android, I found that I have some difficult to enable view in the design editor of android studio 2.3.3.
I only can find view > Tool Windows > Preview. but it is disabled.
How to see the margin value in dp to the top or left of layout for text box added?

Comment: Make sure you area res/layouts/xml file

Comment: thanks, I am in text of xml file. then preview activated.

Comment: I don't have it in "Tool Windows" menu at all